# return false; return true; am confused

Tags: jquery, return

Below is my jquery function

```
function chekTouch($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
      var h1 = $div1.outerHeight();
      var w1 = $div1.outerWidth();
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
      var h2 = $div2.outerHeight();
      var w2 = $div2.outerWidth();
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
}
```

I dont understand what it means to write return false followed by return true.
Can anybody take the pain of explaining me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
```

It is equvivalent to

```
if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) 
{
   return false; //If your condition is true then return false
}
else
{
   return true;  //If condition is false then return true
}
```

> `If` condition contain only one statement then it can write without `brackets` and `If` condition contains multiple statement then it must write within bracket.

Comment: Then can I write if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) alert("1");
      alert("2");  ???

Comment: Yes, You can write if your condition is true then `alert(1)` other wise `alert(2)` will executed.

Comment: @vamsi In the case condition is `true`, both would be alerted because you aren't returning anything before. This is some basic coding behaviour, you should check some tuto imho

Comment: @vamsi Sorry! In your given case if condition is true then both `alert` will executed as commented by @A.Wolff

Comment: If you write `return` keyword then next part of `return` will not executed.

Comment: Now I understood the logic :-) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if the condition ( b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2 ) is met, it will return false.
if not it will always return true.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confused thinking that both statements will be executed. Only one `return` is executed so there is no conflict.

if the `if` condition is true then `return false` is executed and logic flow on that method ends there. It will never reach the next line since method was abandoned when `return false` executed

Comment: Thanks @Claudio Redi, i got it now

Answer (score 0):

**if there are not compound statements i.e. having only one statement , then you can use `if-else` without {}(curly braces)**

```
 if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
```

This simply means that if the check `b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2` collectively returns true then come inside the `if` body and execute `return false` else don't come and execute whatever the next statement is i.e. in your case `return true`